# How to add content to a bootstrap panel by using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

After retrieving info, I want to show it inside a bootstrap panel by using jQuery.

I use the `.html()` function to show the panel.

```
$('#id_div').html('<div class="panel panel-info"><div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">'+my.awesome.title+'</h3></div><div class="panel-body">Content here :) There is more and this is becoming a super long line ...</div></div>');
```

I have found that there is a way to break this into several lines by using `.append()` . I have tried the following:

```
$('#id_div').append('<div class="panel-body">Adding more content here :) </div>');
```

This does not work, since the added text appears outside the panel.

How do I specify where exactly I want the code to be appended?

**Solved.**

According to David, by using the `.find()` function, you can specify where exactly you want the text to be appended.

`$('#id_div').find('.panel-body').append('Adding more content here :)');`

Comment: How about `$(your element).appendTo("#id_div")`?

Comment: Is it inside `$(document).ready(function(){});`?

Comment: @Jezzabeanz Yes, it is.

Comment: Don't you have to target the `panel-body` if you want to append to it ? Or am i misunderstanding your question ?

Comment: @DavidDomain I am trying this `$("<div class='panel-body'>Adding more text!</div>").appendTo('#id_div');` and it is not working either. The new added text is displayed outside the panel.

Comment: *"I have found that there is a way to break this into several lines"* - what's the reason of doing this? If the `.html()` method does work for you, then you can use it.

Comment: @ArturFilipiak because the line will get super long. Like I said in the question.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/r6w2n47L/) ?

Comment: @DavidDomain Yes!, that did the trick! the `.find()` is just what I need.

Comment: @pathros ,ok :-) You can also break it like that: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/j0jktqx1/1/)

Comment: @ArturFilipiak Nice, that does the trick!